# Intercept Touch events in Android

Tags: android, touch

How do I intercept touch events in Android, ensuring that the existing touch workflow is not impacted. Basically I want to add some touch visualizer so as to know where the user is touching on the screen whereby ensuring that if the user is trying to scroll the tableview, touch visualizer is shown as the user drags his finger but also the tableview scrolls with ease.

In iOS, there is one method sendEvent of class UIWindow does this exactly. Not sure if Android has anything similar.

Thanks

Comment: Within Android, touch events flow from a hierachy at the bottom up.  Unless you return true from a touch event, the touch event is not consumed.  Return true from a touch event if you want it to be consumed.  That way you can create multiple touch events on a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [`Activity.dispatchTouchEvent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) and do your touch handling there. Always return `super.dispatchTouchEvent()` to make sure it gets handled the normal way after your logic executes.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    /* your code here */
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Probably this is the method which I was looking for. Quite similar to sendEvent method of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html have alook at this link. It is pretty straight forward. Google it there is lots of example on it.

```
yourview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 return false;
             }
         });
```